# When i hover over the navbar area I want my navbar background to go white while the color of other elements in Navbar goes black. How do i do it?

Tags: css

My Navbar code is like this:

```
<navbar>
      <div className='carousel-container'>
        <Slider />
      </div>
      <div className='navbar'>
        <div className='nav-brand'>
          <h4>e-LECTR0</h4>
          <span style={{ fontSize: '1.5rem' }}>.</span>
        </div>
        <div className='nav-links'>
          <a href='#'>Home</a>
          <a href='#'>Products</a>
          <a href='#'>Contact</a>
          <a href='#'>About Us</a>
        </div>
        <div className='nav-icons'>
          <a href='#'>
            <i class='fi fi-rr-search'></i>
          </a>
          <a href='#'>
            <i class='fi fi-rr-user'></i>
          </a>
          <a href='#'>
            <i class='fi fi-rr-shopping-cart'></i>
          </a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </navbar>

Where as my CSS code:
.navbar {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  padding: 0 2rem;
  padding-top: 1rem !important;
  align-items: center;
  position: relative;
  transition: 0.3s ease-in-out;
}

.navbar:hover {
  background-color: #fff;
}
```

So I want to change the background color of my whole navbar section into white from transparent, which i did. But while hovering into the navbar section I want the other elements in the navbar, such as navbar links and icons, to go black from white color.

How do I do it? Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add `color` to the `.navbar:hover` rule.

```
.navbar:hover {
  background-color: #fff;
  color: black;
}
```

If the inheritance isn't working correctly, you can be explicit:

```
.navbar:hover {
  background-color: #fff;
}

.navbar:hover > * {
  color: black;
}
```

There are ways you can be more explicit, but if the code above isn't working, then I expect there is a specificity conflict.  Check the style rules for the elements inside the `navbar` to make sure that you aren't overwriting the style change from the `hover` rule.

You can do this by inspecting the element in the browser developer tools, and you will see all rules affecting that element in specificity order, and that will help you track down where your style is being overwritten.

Comment: Thanks dude. I will try it and look into it.

Comment: .navbar:hover {
  background-color: #fff;
}

.navbar:hover > .nav-links a {
  color: black;
}

.navbar:hover > .nav-brand {
  color: #000;
}

.navbar:hover > .nav-icons a {
  color: #000;
}
this worked fine for me. Thanks PsiKai for your help .

Comment: You might be able to do all that at once by declaring `.navbar:hover * {color: #000;}`.  The `*` is a wildcard meaning, "every element that is inside this selector".  This is slightly different than the answer I provided with `> *` which selects only direct children (not nested children).

Comment: Also, happy to help.  If I was able to answer you question, please mark the answer as correct so I can get those sweet rep points ;)

Comment: Done what u requested. :D